# Which European country is most likely to offer an American citizen asylum?

Tags: usa, europe, us-citizens, refugees

Which European country is most likely to offer an American citizen asylum?

If a hypothetical American were fleeing an abusive domestic relationship with someone extremely powerful and hard to challenge or hold to account within the US system, and we're liable to be denied resolution and future safety by any of the ostensibly responsible US institutions, which country in Europe would he have the highest chance of being granted recognition of his situation and real refuge by?

Please tell if this is wrong or not, but my intuitive sesne is that close allies would not be inclined to grant us citizens refuge because it sort of insults the original country. Which, in case accurate, rules out... UK? France? maybe Germany? Estonia? Poland? How is that list? Of course this is merely extrapolating from the overall diplomatic relationship but it would be far more useful to either speculate from countries' direct laws and policies regarding granting refuge to various Nationals, or better yet, to cite real historical empirical precedents if they exist.

Informative answers greatly appreciated!

Comment: However, I have been told of a case of successful acquisition of Asylum status in a similar situation but with the danger being Australian and Asylum bring granted by the US.

Comment: Maybe you should ask Edward Snowden; I suppose he'd answer "Russia."

Comment: The only successful applications I have heard of recently were in Canada and Russia, Western/Central Europe does not seem like a particularly attractive destination.

Comment: and what does this have to do with travel?

Comment: Relevant article in the Washington Post: [**Can an American become a refugee? Yes, and some already have**](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2017/01/20/can-an-american-become-a-refugee-yes-and-some-already-have/?utm_term=.b37c6ba3ed56). Doesn't contain the answer to your question but quotes stats showing that some US citizens have been granted refugee status in Europe, and gives an example that was a complex domestic abuse/child custody case

Comment: John, it looks like people have decided this question is off topic here because it's about permanent/long-term migration. But I think your question is on-topic to ask at the Expatriates sister site here: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This seems more like a work of fiction (with a thinly veiled reference to the current POTUS) rather than an actual problem. Maybe try world building stack exchange?

Comment: Andrew, your assumption is both naive and slightly harmful. User568458, great thanks for your suggestion! What's the right way to do that - isn't there some kind of proper mechanism for "migrating" questions or something? Also, thanks for the wapo piece. I look forward to having a read of it and expect it to be informative.

Answer (score 1):

**Seems I am wrong**
See what was written in the comments by @user568458:

> You'd be surprised, there are a small number of US citizens granted asylum in EU countries every year and it's not a big deal diplomatically. Has been true for years. This WP article has a good summary and quotes a good stat: "12 U.S. citizens were granted asylum in Britain in 2015, meaning about 1 in 5 applications were successful"...
>
> ...generally the asylum application experience is different for people from countries like the US because they usually have a valid (temporary) visa already, speak English, etc, plus it's relatively rare, so generally those of us who volunteer at centres, outreach programmes, detention centres etc almost never encounter them (I never did when I used to volunteer). But they do exist

**My original answer**
Non of the European Union countries.

They will expect the USA to be able to protect its own citizens, and as such asylum will not be granted. Asylum is not easily given, not even to citizens of countries where the government is the reason the citizen has to flee for his life.

They might be willing to give grant to reside more easily than they would for other applicants, but that will be the officers to decide, not the system granting it as a rule.

You can try Russia, as it has proven to be willing to allow USA citizens unwilling to stay in the USA.

Comment: This answer seems to be based on exactly nothing but speculation and common sense, with no knowledge of the asylum system.

Comment: Just on following the news for my whole life, with someone who volunteerd in helping newly arrived refugees. That made me aware of the general rules and the notable exceptions.

Comment: You'd be surprised, there are a small number of US citizens granted asylum in EU countries every year and it's not a big deal diplomatically. Has been true for years. [This WP article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2017/01/20/can-an-american-become-a-refugee-yes-and-some-already-have/?utm_term=.b37c6ba3ed56) has a good summary and quotes a good stat: "12 U.S. citizens were granted asylum in Britain in 2015, meaning about 1 in 5 applications were successful"...

Comment: ...generally the asylum application experience is different for people from countries like the US because they usually have a valid (temporary) visa already, speak English, etc, plus it's relatively rare, so generally those of us who volunteer at centres, outreach programmes, detention centres etc almost never encounter them (I never did when I used to volunteer). But they do exist

Answer (score 1):

From your list, Germany would certainly come before France as a close US ally, yet it is very by-the-book and would still process such an application. Politics might certainly play a role at the end of the day but there is for example [a famous recent case](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Shepherd) of a US citizen seeking refugee status there. Every decision until now has been negative but he is still going through the appeal process, it's not like the interior ministry would put him back in a plane or summarily deny the application merely because he is a US citizen. I know there have been a bunch of cases like that in the UK and Sweden too but I don't recall anyone being successful in recent years.

Generally speaking, the rules do not discriminate between nationalities at all, each claim has to be judged on the merits. The closest you will find to a nationality-of-origin standard is the notion of a “safe country of origin” (this exists in German law for example) but these lists are typically very short and limited to countries in the Balkan that have seen trouble in the past. So you won't find any clear-cut rule about US citizens. And there are so few cases that statistics are essentially meaningless.

Beyond that, Australian example notwithstanding, the situation you described does not seem to match the international definition of a refugee very well and it would therefore seem extremely unlikely to see such a claim accepted.

Comment: Hi Relaxed, and thank you for your clear, informative answer. Do you know if it would be possible, and either wise or especially unadvisable to submit multiple simultaneous applications to different countries to better one's odds, a bit like people apply to universities?

Comment: @John No, this is typically not possible. In the Schengen area, there is even a database of asylum seekers so that member countries can easily find out about applications that were lodged elsewhere (EURODAC).

Comment: @John, generally you should make your asylum application in the first EU country you enter. An US citizen traveling on his legitimate passport would leave a paper trail.

Comment: @o.m. Actually, not much, just an entry stamp. And there is absolutely no obligation to apply in the first EU country you enter. But if you want to target one, it's best to enter there directly of course.

Comment: @Relaxed, the Dublin accords have not been enforced with regards to Greece and the Balkan route, but for many other constellations they are still applied.

Comment: @o.m. That's not my point, the Dublin system (it's grounded in EU regulations now, not a separate convention) entails absolutely no obligation for refugees to seek protection in a specific country. People keep writing that on this site but it's simply not true.

Comment: It's only *after* an application has been lodged that the Dublin rules are engaged. Refugees can apply to have their status recognised in any EU country and that country can then try a Dublin take-charge request. But there are many special situations and procedural details and if it fails, it *has to* process the application and the asylum seeker has lost nothing. Furthermore, in this particular case, the Dublin regulation does not apply, at all (cf. article 14), at least as far as Schengen countries are concerned.

Comment: @Relaxed, you're right, I did not think of this exception for visa waiver countries.

Comment: Relaxed, I thank you again for your informative answers.